# How to set a cursor for Header of JTable?

Tags: java, swing, cursor, jtable, jtableheader

I used **setCursor()** method to set a cursor for JTable.
But that cursor is applying only for rows (datapart) of the table.
How can I set cursor for Header of the same table,so that I can resize the column by double clicking its(column's) right edge?

Comment: and please seach on this forum, sometimes doesn't works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
table.getTableHeader().setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
```